# How to automatically number columns in calc/excel

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc

In spreadsheet software such as LibreOffice Calc, or MS Excel, rows are numbered starting at 1, and column identifiers are assigned with a letter (A, B, C, etc.).

Is it possible to add an extra row and enumerate all columns progamatically like in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: That works! Can you add it as an answer so I can close the question?

Comment: I wasn't looking for a specific function. In fact, I've just discovered that you can enter manually 1 (in A1), and 2 (in B1), and extending to the rest of columns (as when using a function) does the same trick. However, I think it is more elegant to use a function; why would it be off topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=COLUMN()
```

in either, or switch Excel Options (Formulas, Working with formulas in Excel 2013) to R1C1 reference style.